# Sorted java data structure with efficient add and indexed get method

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there a data structure implemented in java that provide the following guarentees:

- Elements are always sorted
- Adding a element performs at least at O(lg n)
- Getting an element at a specific index performs at least at O(lg n)

Basically I would like to be able to do the following:

```
SomeDataStructure elements = new SomeDataStructure();
elements.add(5);
elements.add(1);
elements.add(10);
assertEquals(1, elements.get(0));
assertEquals(5, elements.get(1));
assertEquals(10, elements.get(2));
```

where both the `add` and `get` methods both performed at least at O(lg n).

This seems like it should be able to be done with a tree structure but I cannot find any implementations that provides indexed get methods.  I also looked into using/extending a java.util.TreeMap for this but all of the rotation logic is private so I cannot track how the tree is being changed.

Comment: There's no such thing without a third-party library, unless you're willing to write your own.

Comment: I am fine with using a third party.  I am trying to avoid writing it myself.

Comment: I don't actually know of any third-party libraries that provide this, either.  It's not a very common need.

Comment: Do you need to interleave reads and writes?

Comment: Is the index based on `Comparable` order, or insertion order?

Comment: I don't need to interleave reads and writes.

Comment: The index is based on Comparable order, I will update the code sample.

Comment: If you don't need to interleave reads and writes, what's wrong with putting all your elements in a list, sorting the list, and using indexes into the sorted list?

Comment: @Alex I think it's the additional runtime of O(n * log(n)) for sorting. But I guess, adding `n` elements to a set, where each adding is O(log(n)) will have the same effect, as adding them in O(1) to a list and afterwards sorting...

Comment: @Baz But adding n items to a list in O(log(n)) time per item still gives O(n*log(n)). The overall complexity is the same.

Comment: @Alex Just edited my comment while you were typing. Seems we are on the same side :)

Comment: Yes the overall complexity will be O(n*log(n)) for either sorting an unordered list or adding n elements to a list that sorts while you add them.  But I am trying to calculate various percentiles of large streams of numbers that will stream in over an extended period of time.  I will have plenty of time to sort as the numbers are added to the data structure but I need to be able to compute the percentiles very quickly.

Comment: @Yanamon This sounds a little bit like premature optimization to me. Do you assume that the sort will be too slow, or do you have the numbers to show it? If you really can't afford the sort, then I think what you want is a tree structure where each node records the number of children on each branch. It would be pretty straightforward to write an indexed lookup on that structure. I don't know if anything like that exists that you can just use out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use `TreeMap`, and then add a `get` method that traversed the tree to get that index?

you might be able to use the `keySet` iterator to walk them in order, but there's no documentation on the performance of that.

Comment: That will yield O(n) lookups, he's asking for O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to interleave reads and writes -- i.e., you want to build your data structure all at once and then look things up in it, without ever having to modify it after it's built -- then I would simply build up a list, sort it, and then use indexes into the list. A tree is overkill in this situation because you don't need to keep the structure sorted while you're building it up.

```
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
elements.add(5);
elements.add(1);
elements.add(10);

Collections.sort(elements);

assertEquals(1, elements.get(0));
assertEquals(5, elements.get(1));
assertEquals(10, elements.get(2));
```

The adds happen in O(1) time each (so O(n) for adding n items) and the sort happens in O(n * log(n)) time, giving you an overall complexity of O(n + n * log(n)) = O(n * log(n)) for building the structure. This is the same as adding n elements in O(log(n)) time each. Lookups, however, will happen in constant (O(1)) time, giving you better efficiency than a tree-based solution.

If you want to guarantee that the structure is never modified (i.e. never loses its sorting), you could replace the 5th line above with:

```
elements = Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.sort(elements));
```

This will throw an exception if anybody ever tries to modify the list, which would be a clue to you that something wrong is going on.

Comment: Collections.sort(elements) is an O(n lg(n)) operation.  Also adding to an ArrayList is an O(n) if the array needs to be extended.

Comment: Yes, I said the sort is O(n * log(n)) in the answer. If you're worried about O(n) insertions when extending the array, then build it up as a linked list and copy it into an array when you're done. The important thing is that the *overall complexity* of this approach is O(n * log(n)), which is the same as what you would get by building up a tree.

Answer (score -1):

From the [JavaSE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for TreeMap:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

You can find out the same by looking up info about whichever implementation you're using.

Comment: `TreeMap` doesn't let you get an element at a specified index.

Comment: I don't have an id, I want to access the element at a specific index.

Comment: ok got it, and index is relative to the ordering right? so index = 2 is the third to smallest element?